# How to solve "The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler."?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I hosted my website in server But it show in 
[image]

And i run aspnet_regiis.exe -i file also .But my site shows this error how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked if it uses the correct application pool?

Comment: Yes it in correct application pool